# The ampersand (&) character is not allowed

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm trying to add my environment variables for an app through the console and one of those is the database link. It contains an & in it and I don't know how to fix that.

I saw somewhere to try and add "", '' or (slash, I'm new to stack overflow don't mind it)"" but it didn't work. What can I do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "database link" you meant some sort of DB URL, for example `mysql://...` then it got to be urlencoded.

So replace `&` with `%26`

Comment: I just tried it and it said "...true%26w=majority' (the part with the & of the db url) is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

Do I need to wrap it in ${} or something? I'm very new to coding.

Comment: I had forgotten to write heroku at the start of the line........ 
thank you so much though <3